# What kind of damage is this on a wool suit?

Tags: fabric, wool

This lumpy pattern developed on the breast panel of this wool suit that has been dry cleaned, ironed, and hanging in a closet next to other suits.  It has been a few months since I wore it, and I didn't notice this earlier although it may have developed slowly or suddenly.  Other things in the closet, and the pants hanging on the same hanger, do not have this damage.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it remained wet for longer than the adjacent area. Could something wet have been hanging right next to it?

Comment: @Joachim No not next to it, and I usually leave a suit hanging outside the closet for a day before putting it back.  Are you are saying this could be caused by water?  There are other explanations .... If I came in from the rain or leaned on something wet and put it straight away in the closet could that kind of thing cause this?   Of course, I've come in from the rain hundreds of times in my life so it's suspicious that this never happened before.

Comment: It looks like it was locally kept wet for a prolonged time, yes, but it could be caused by other things I'm just not aware of. The fibres seem to have warped. You could try ironing one of the patches to see if that will flatten it out again (but maybe wait for a second opinion on this - there are users better-versed in all things clothing here :).

Comment: Sorry about the suit wrinkles, but is this really an art/craft question? And even so its more guess work. For example... is the material possibly a wool blend and scorched by the cleaners and you didn't see it until now? Water damage is not bad idea, but it looks as if it were held against gravel for a length of time, maybe something was on the wall behind it or in the car on the way home from the cleaners that was pressed into it. Etc.

Comment: I've seen a similar pattern in a [question over on Lifehacks.SE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/26447/26801) that was caused by either low quality fabric or overheating the fabric and damaging the elastic thread that was woven into it. If the straight fabric is stretchier than the dented areas, this might be a lost cause. Otherwise try ironing the jacket without steam and put a clean, dry cloth (dish towel works well) between the fabric and the iron to avoid marks. Let the fabric cool flat on the ironing board or you might introduce new bumps and wrinkles.